# How to replace a $ in a string in perl script

Tags: perl

I have a string,
$str = abc#$and@def

I tried to replace '$' with it's hex value using ,

$str=~s/$/%26/g

But the output is abc#.

This might be because '$'is considered as the end of the line or string.

Please let me know

Comment: I hate to sound like a crochety old n00b-hater but I'm considering a blanket policy of downvoting all Perl questions that could have been solved with `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Always show complete programs (with input) that demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` with a `\`

```
$str =~ s/\$/%26/g
```

Comment: It definitely works, you must have some other issues. Make sure you have `use strict;` at the start of your script. Look here http://ideone.com/5cf4d

Comment: Thanks it is working! Now I have a new issue, This string is part of input array argv, So when I run the foreach loop, the value of the string read only till $ and not beyond that.. Would be glad if I can get help on that.

Comment: Sorry @Mini I don't know what you mean. Maybe post another question which includes the problem code

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is nothing to do with your substitution; when you are assigning to the string in the first place:

```
$str = "abc#$and@def";
```

`$and` and `@def` are treated as variables to interpolate.

You need to escape the sigils or use single quotes (which don't interpolate variables):

```
$str = 'abc#$and@def';
# or
$str = "abc#\$and\@def";
```

And you really really need to enable warnings, which would have told you your assignment was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the $ with a \:

```
$str =~ s/\$/%26/g;
```

Ron

Comment: This works only of $ is already escaped in the string. But in myscenario the it is not escaped, so '$' is considered as end of string and the parsing stops right there!